# Does every method is defined in an object has hidden link to Function.prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
var obj = {
         name : 'abc',
         getName : function () {
                     return this.name;
                   }
         }
```

In this code obj will have hidden link to Object.prototype. But does obj.getName() also has hidden link to Function.prototype.

Comment: The question is, do all function objects that are created by function expressions, inherit from `Function.prototype`, and the answer is yes.

Comment: So it doesn't matter if that function object is assigned to key in a object or assigned to a independent var?  Its still gonna have hidden link to Function.prototype.

Comment: Note: It's not actually that "*hidden*." Every instance knows its [`constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor). So, `obj.constructor === Object` and `obj.getName.constructor === Function`.

Answer (score 0):

Of course. Any object has a "hidden link" to its prototype. Objects, strings, arrays, functions, numbers, documents, nodes, windows... anything at all, in fact.

Comment: Strings, and numbers are primitive values, not objects (so they don't have a prototype). (I'm intentionally leaving out String objects and Number objects which should explicitly be noted as "String objects" and "Number objects" to avoid confusion.) As for documents, nodes, and windows, that is left up to the implementation (so it's not an "of course"), although afaik all browser vendors *do* define prototypes for those types of objects.

Comment: `(2).constructor` returns the `Number` object, showing that even though `2` is a literal, primitive value, it is being wrapped in a Number object. That is how, for example, I can call `(1.2345).toFixed(2)` and get a result instead of an error.

Comment: I understand if function object was created independently ( e.g var add = function() {}; ) it will have link to Function.Prototype. But my question was when same function object is property of another object will it still have hidden link to Function.prototype? when object already has  hidden link to Object.prototype.

Comment: @user1130687 Yes... why would it be any different being a property of an object, when things like global variables are properties of the window object anyway?

Comment: Yes, I understand that. My comment was about semantics. The term "number" can mean either a primitive Number value or a Number object. To avoid confusion, it's best to use "number" (implicitly) for primitive Number values, and "Number object" (explicitly) for Number objects.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Fair enough. I really should have Proper Cased those names.